# Is there a way to specify order-dependent "at least one of these" in antlr4?

Tags: antlr4

I have a rule:

```
element
    : first
    | second
    | first second
    ;
```

I can shrink it down slightly:

```
element
    : first
    | first? second
    ;
```

Is there a better way to write this? Something like `first <andor> second` where `<andor>` is the magic I need?

Same question for lexer rules:

```
FP
    : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*
    | [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to make this simpler. The only change I'd suggest is that you make the second part optional, not the first one. This should give you a (slight) performance improvement, because the prediction algorithm doesn't have to visit two paths (one with and one w/o the first optional part) to know if an alternative can match:

```
element
    : first second?
    | second
    ;
```

Comment: Good advice. That makes a lot of sense.